# Add fadein to this .on function

Tags: jquery, fadein

Is there a way that I can add a .fadein method to the following jQuery code?;

Currently when you hover over the .button div it shows another div with a corresponding ID, but the change is instant and it looks a bit jerky so I wanted to add a nice little fade between each transition

```
$(".button").on("mouseover",function(){
    $('div.tagline').hide();
    $('#tag-' + this.id).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
 $('div.tagline').hide();
 $('#tag-' + this.id).show();
```

with

```
 $('div.tagline').fadeOut();
 $('#tag-' + this.id).fadeIn();
```

written in this form the fadeIn and fadeOut will be executed at the same time (in parallel): if you want ends the fadeOut and then execute the fadeIn just write

```
 var self = this;
 $('div.tagline').fadeOut(function() {
     $('#tag-' + self.id).fadeIn();
 });
```

Comment: The second option worked, but it has a strange "flashing" effect now. Is there any way I can stop that? - http://www.robotwp.com/overseas/

Answer (score 0):

Just try like that :

```
$(".button").on("mouseover",function(){
    $('div.tagline').stop().fadeOut();
    $('#tag-' + this.id).stop().fadeIn();
});
```

You might need to add the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method if it's flickers.

Comment: This works, but there's a "flashing" effect on there now. Can I remove that? http://www.robotwp.com/overseas/

Comment: Now the text doesn't appear... The effect is there but the text isn't